# Dynamically replace HTML element in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have some HTML loaded in WebView like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>before  <myTag>Content</myTag>  after</body></html>
```

I want to replace element `myTag` with custom text so it should look like:

```
 <html><head></head><body>before  ____MY_CUSTOM_TEXT___  after</body></html>
```

Also I can't change initial HTML. 
How I can do this with JavaScript?

My not finished code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName( 'myTag' );
var firstElement = elements[0];
var parentElement = firstElement.parentNode;
var html = parentElement.innerHTML;
parentElement.innerHTML = html.replace(?????, '____MY_CUSTOM_TEXT___');
```

I don't know how to get string value of element to replace (?????).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode('____MY_CUSTOM_TEXT___');
parentElement.replaceChild(txt, firstElement);
```